# How to stop UseEffect from running outside code

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am new to React Native. I have a stopwatch that re-renders on screen every 10 milliseconds. However, functions that I have written outside of the useEffect hook are getting called every ten seconds as well. For instance, I have a function that I only want to run when a button is pressed. Nowhere is the function called in useEffect, but it runs every 10 milliseconds, even if the button is not pressed. How can I avoid this issue?

```
useEffect(() => {
    let interval = null;

    if (timerOn) {
      let startTime = new Date().getTime();
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        var currentTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
        setTime(
          `${padToTwo(Math.floor((currentTime / 3600000) % 24))}:${padToTwo(
            Math.floor((currentTime / 60000) % 60)
          )}:${padToTwo(Math.floor((currentTime / 1000) % 60))}:${padToTwo(
            currentTime % 100
          )}`
        );
      }, 10);
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [timerOn]);
```

Comment: Please share the full component, Because mostly its not an issue with `useEffect` its most probably about other thing in the component

Answer (score 1):

you can use another state.

```
const [useOne,setUseOne] = useState<boolean>(true)

useEffect(() => {

if (useOne) {

let interval = null;

    if (timerOn) {
      let startTime = new Date().getTime();
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        var currentTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
        setTime(
          `${padToTwo(Math.floor((currentTime / 3600000) % 24))}:${padToTwo(
            Math.floor((currentTime / 60000) % 60)
          )}:${padToTwo(Math.floor((currentTime / 1000) % 60))}:${padToTwo(
            currentTime % 100
          )}`
        );
      }, 10);
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

}
    
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [timerOn,useOne]);


....
<Button title="off" onPress={() => useOne(false)} />
```